# Reducing Line Spacing of Text in SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui, line-spacing

For some fonts, the built-in line spacing is unpleasantly large.

SwiftUI gives us the `Text` modifier **`.lineSpacing()`** to adjust the spacing between lines of text (also called the *leading*, unrelated to leading/trailing). Its value specifies the number of points of additional spacing to place between consecutive lines of text, so that `.lineSpacing(0)` results in no change. Unfortunately, it does not appear to respond to negative values; `.lineSpacing(-10)` yields the same result as `lineSpacing(0)`.

Does anyone know of a way to reduce line spacing in SwiftUI without resorting to UIKit?

Comment: It is not a replacement, it is addition. Here is doc: "This value is always nonnegative. This value is included in the line fragment heights in the layout manager."

Comment: Yes, we know the value is in addition to normal spacing, not a replacement for it, because .lineSpacing(0) is intended to have no effect. Thank you @Asperi - but still looking for a solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you could wrap `UILabel` to reduce line height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68288238/7337835

Comment: Thanks, @TotoMinai—but, as I mentioned in the original post, I'm looking for a SwiftUI solution that doesn't use UIKit.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to gain free control over negative line spacing in SwiftUI (as it ships in iOS 16 atm). My reasoning for this assessment:r as Text() seems to insist that the only compression you can make to the leading is down to Font.leading.tight

Comment: I found this when searching for the solution: https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9842474
It uses an undocumented (but maybe not private) `_lineHeightMultiple` modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think it's possible to gain free control over negative line spacing in SwiftUI atm — as of Fall '22 all negative values create the same, only marginally tighter leading, no matter the value — you *can* reduce the leading of the Font itself, by applying [.leading(.tight)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/leading(_:)) to the Font. This did tighten a quick test example beyond what the negative value cap of .lineSpacing(-X) seems to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Unfortunately this stopped working in Xcode 15 as the function is now marked internal and there is no other option available. Damn Apple!

---

Based on tadelv comment.

`lineSpacing` does not accept negative values, but you have a hidden API `_lineHeightMultiple` that works. It says it's deprecated but the suggested one does not exist!

```
var body: some View {
  let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
  let fontLineHeight = font.lineHeight
  let desiredLineHeight = 24.0

  Text("text")
    .font(Font(font))
    ._lineHeightMultiple(desiredLineHeight / fontLineHeight)
}
```

Remember that using private apis could be rejected by App Store Review or break on future ios versions. Use at your own risk! (Damn Apple!)

Comment: This now produces a compilation error in Xcode 15 because it has been marked as `internal`

Comment: Has anyone found a workaround on this?

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in iOS 17 there's an Environment modifyier that you use to increase/decrease line spacing:

```
MyView()
.environment(\._lineHeightMultiple, 0.9)
```

Not sure if its a 100% public API but it does the job.

Comment: Probably not part of the public API because of the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '\n' to denote line breaks and use the following:

```
struct CustomTextView: View {
  var text: String
  var font: Font
  var lineSpacing: CGFloat

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: lineSpacing) {
      ForEach(text.components(separatedBy: "\n"), id: \.self) { line in
        Text(line)
          .font(font)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it works using negative values in some way.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYChV.png)

First image has lineSpacing set to -3, second set to 0.

-3 is the less value where I can see some effects.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

You can split up the text in multiple lines and apply negative padding around each one like this:

```
Text("This is the first Line")
    .padding(-10)
Text("This is the second Line")
    .padding(-10)
```

Comment: Thanks, @user14952184. A good idea for the special case where you don't need any automatic text wrapping. Though not for the general case.

Comment: This leads to undesirable behavior with VoiceOver and DynamicType.